# Multi Channel Funnel API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am sure this is staring me right in the face but how can I access the Multi Channel Funnel data via Google Sheets API plugin?

Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

What I am looking to get is:

- mcf:basicChannelGroupingPath

by:

- Users That Ordered
- Users that Didn't Order.

If I need to link the data together separately I just need to know how to pull that unique user identified for users and then map order ids.

Comment: It was auto added by Stack Overflow.  It has been removed.